# Evaluate values of xyz

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

If $a,$  $b$ and $c$ are angles such that $$\tan a + \tan b + \tan c = \tan a\tan b\tan c$$ and $$x = \cos a + i\sin a,$$ $$y = \cos b + i\sin b$$ and $$z = \cos c + i\sin c$$ then find the values of $xyz$.

Comment: All of x, y, and z have absolute value 1 so we cam write these as $x= e^{ai}$, $y= e^{bi}$, and $z= e^{ci}$.  So $xyz= e^{(a+ b+ c)I}$.  Can you use that "tangent" condition to determine a+ b+ c?

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan{a}+\tan{b}+\tan{c}(1-\tan{a}\tan{b})=0$$ or
$$\tan(a+b)+\tan{c}=0$$ or
$$\sin(a+b+c)=0.$$
Id est, $$xyz=\cos(a+b+c)+i\sin(a+b+c)=\pm1.$$

Answer (score 1):

From $\tan a+\tan b+\tan c=\tan a\tan b\tan c$ you can deduce that
$${\tan a+\tan b\over 1-\tan a\cdot \tan b }=-\tan c$$

so $a+b +c= \pi \cdot k$, for some integer $k$.

Thus $ xyz = e^{ia}e^{ib}e^{ic} =e^{i(a+b+c)} = e^{i\pi k} = \pm 1$

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$\tan(a+b+c)=\frac{\tan a+\tan b+\tan c-\tan a\tan b\tan c}{\text{some stuff}}.$$